# deploying Web Project frontend html css and js Backend node js, express js and mongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have web development project hows front end is being built using HTML5 CSS and JAVASCRIPT and Your backend is node JavaScript, Express JavaScript, and MYSQL as a database
know I have shared hosting available on Name Cheap and know i want to deploy my project how i can achieve this

I have tried using VPS service as well but couldn't achieve it. know I am back to shared hosting of Namecheap and want this project to be deployed with the backend completely working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.